# I want to match response with #uuid but Karate does not read value but #uuid

Tags: karate

This is my response

```
{
  "code": "code",
  "messages": [
    "id -1 not found for user id: c0280b98-0c49-4718-ab99-a6f246dcafde"
  ]
}
```

This is my match

```
* match response == {"code": "code","messages": ["id -1 not found for user id: #uuid "]}
```

This is error I get

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: match failed: EQUALS
  $ | not equal | match failed for name: 'messages' (MAP:MAP)
  {"code":"code","messages":["id -1 not found for user id: c0280b98-0c49-4718-ab99-a6f246dcafde"]}
  {"code":"code","messages":["id -1 not found for user id: #uuid "]}
```

I tried #notnull #present and still get same response. Don't know is it because double quote in response or am I just doing something wrong. I also tried to *def expected and than do the match but error is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `#regex`:

```
* match response == { code: 'code', messages: [ '#regex id -1 not found for user id: .+' ] }
```

Or:

```
* match response == { code: 'code', messages: [ '#regex id -1 not found for user id: [-0-9a-f]+' ] }
```

Otherwise, you can't combine a '#uuid'. You could "extract" that part and run a separate match if you wanted, but I personally think that's un-necessary.

```
* def temp = response.messages[0].split(' ')
* def uuidPart = temp[temp.length - 1]
* match uuidPart == '#uuid'
```